# NodeJS: module.exports property is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following in a module file:

```
module.exports = {
    myfunc: myfunc
};

var myfunc = function(callback){    
        callback(err,reply);    
};
```

In an other file I got the reference to that module

```
var mymodule = require('./modules/mymodule');
mymodule.myfunc(function(err, reply){ ... });
```

When I call the mymodule.myfunc() I get an error saying "property 'myfunc' is not a function".
This happens only with exported functions. The same module exports some 'string' fields and these are working just fine.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When you assign `module.exports`, the `myfunc` function is still undefined. Try to assign it after declaring it:

```
var myfunc = function(callback){    
    callback(err,reply);    
};

module.exports = {
    myfunc: myfunc
};
```

Comment: well, that was embarrassing.. Thanks.

Comment: I've defined my function with `const myfunc ...` and then tried to export it at the end and I still get a similar error... can I not export a function with `const` access modifier?

Comment: Edit: that was embarrassing. Apparently I used `exports = {}` directly and that messed everything up: https://adrianmejia.com/blog/2016/08/12/getting-started-with-node-js-modules-require-exports-imports-npm-and-beyond/#Module-exports-vs-Exports

Answer (score 11):

To preserve your original ordering of module.exports at the top of your file, change your `var myfunc` **initialization** to a `function myfunc` **declaration** so that the latter is ***hoisted***.

```
module.exports = {
    myfunc: myfunc
};

function myfunc(callback){    
    callback(err,reply);    
};
```

Declarations are ***hoisted***, but initializations are not, which is why your original example did not work.  w3schools has a practical description of [JavaScript Hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp).

Comment: Am a beginner in these,  can i know why ` myfunc: myfunc` is used means what does that mean

Comment: @AmritBera `module.exports` is assigned to an object. In JS, an object is constructed using key-value pairs surrounded by curly braces. 

For instance, `let obj = { foo: 'bar' }`. This answer shows an object with a key named `myfunc` associated to a value that is a function also named `myfunc`.

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario where i found this annoying issue was if explicitly imported only the function that my consumer needs

Say for example your exported modules looks like below

```
module.exports = {
    func1 : async function func1(){}
    func2 : async function func2(){
        await this.func1(); // causes error : func1 is not a function
    }
}
```

Now your consumer of above module looks like below:

```
const { func2 } = require('../theExportedModules'); 
//above only imports func2 but not its dependents and is not initialized    
await func2(); //func2 called
```

Now `func2()` gets called from your consumer but `func2()` will not be able to call the `func1()` because it finds that `func1()` is not a function. Code breaks!

solution import entire modules:

```
const theExportedModules = require('../theExportedModules');
```

we could also just import func1 as well but then it would be an unused variable and we would get a warning for that.